# prove $((A\Delta B)^c = A \cap B) \to ((A\cup B)^c = \emptyset)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm not quite sure about how to prove that $((A\Delta B)^c = A \cap B) \to ((A\cup B)^c = \emptyset)$.

what I came to is attached, but can I just conclude from it that $A^c \cap B^c$ is an empty set?? thanks in advanced.
[image]

Comment: If we just know that $(A^c \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap B) = A \cap B$, all we can really say is that $(A^c \cap B^c) \subseteq A \cap B$. So you'll probably need a bit after that, to show emptiness.

Comment: yes, I could see that as well. but no clue how to show emptiness.. contradiction? no idea how to use contradiction here.

Comment: You can conclude using the fact that the LHS in your last equality is actually a **disjoint** union.

Answer (score 2):

You've concluded that $(A^c\cap B^c)\cup (A\cap B)= A\cap B$, or in other words $(A^c\cap B^c)\subseteq A\cap B$.

But we already know that $(A^c\cap B^c)$ is *disjoint from* $(A\cap B)$, that is, $(A^c\cap B^c)\cap (A\cap B)=\emptyset$! (Do you see why?)

Combining these two facts, we get that $(A^c\cap B^c)=(A^c\cap B^c)\cap (A\cap B)=\emptyset.$

Answer (score 2):

$(A\triangle B)^c = A\cap B$ means that the intersection of A and B is *everything* that is not in the symmetric difference of A and B.   But the symmetric difference excludes *both* the intersection *and* the complement of the union (ie: everything that is not in either A or B).   These are mutually exclusive sets.   That means there can be nothing in the complement of the union.

$$(A\triangle B)^c = A\cap B
\\ \Updownarrow 
\\ \big((A\cup B)\cap (A\cap B)^c\big)^c = (A\cap B)
\\ \Updownarrow \\
(A\cup B)^c\cup(A\cap B) = (A\cap B)
\\ \Updownarrow \\
(A\cup B)^c \subseteq (A\cap B)
\\ \Updownarrow \\
(A^c\cap B^c) \subseteq (A\cap B)
\\ \Downarrow \\
(A^c\cap B^c) \subseteq A
\\ \Downarrow \\
(A^c\cap B^c) = \emptyset
$$

---

$\therefore \Big((A\triangle B)^c = A\cap B\Big) \to \Big((A^c\cap B^c) = \emptyset\Big) \\ \Box$

Answer (score 1):

Everything you wrote is correct. For contradiction, assume $A^c\cap B^c\neq \varnothing$. Then exists $x\in A^c\cap B^c$, so $x\in(A^c\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap B)=A\cap B$.

But $x\in A^C, x\in B^c$, so $x\not\in A, x\not\in B$, so $x\not\in A\cap B$,  contradiction.